# I need to have a space and comma in State dropdown value in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this dropdown in Angular 9, but when the State is more that one, I don't have space between, it shows like:

```
    Licensed State:ARCA

    I need like: AR, CA
```

this is my code:

```
             <ng-container *ngIf="realEstateAgent.licenseNumbers?.length < 3 else stateCount">
                <span *ngFor="let license of realEstateAgent.licenseNumbers;"
                    class="directory-card__state">{{ license.state | uppercase }}</span>
            </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you please create a simple demo with stackblitz or anything of that kind, illustrating the underlaying issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code

```
<ng-container *ngIf="realEstateAgent.licenseNumbers?.length < 3 else stateCount">
                <span *ngFor="let license of realEstateAgent.licenseNumbers; let i=index;"
                    class="directory-card__state"> {{ license.state | uppercase }}<ng-container *ngIf="i< realEstateAgent.licenseNumbers.length-1">,</ng-container>
                    </span>
            </ng-container>
```

Stack blitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-al9toi